# Show Local notification without sound

Tags: iphone, ios, uilocalnotification

I am using local notificaitons in my ios app.  Is there a way for me to show an iOS local notification with only a vibration and display, without playing any sound?

Comment: Have you tried setting `soundName` to `nil`?

Comment: Yes I have, it actually made the notification not appear at all.  Has that worked for you?

Comment: For the push or for a local notification? They are different things.

Comment: oops, sorry about that, this is only for my local notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry friend it is not possible with the UILocalNotification

UILocalNotification API lets you set the system default sound, choose a sound, or have no sound, and if you have some sound, it will vibrate under the right circumstances (i.e., if you have enabled the vibration from phone settings).But you have no control on settings the vibration for your UILocalnotification.